# PHP fopen() fails to open url resource

Tags: php, url, fopen

I'd like to fopen this url: http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/hlth_cd_asdr/A..T.TOTAL.A-R_V-Y./startperiod=2010&endPeriod=2010
like this:

```
$stream=fopen('http://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/SDMX/diss-web/rest/data/hlth_cd_asdr/A..T.TOTAL.A-R_V-Y./startperiod=2010&endPeriod=2010','r');
```

but it fails with the following warning:

```
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 502 Bad Gateway
```

What should I do to open this link in PHP?

Comment: Have a look here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.http.php and here: http://php.net/manual/en/httprequest.send.php

Comment: So, is it not possible with fopen() or file_get_contents() only? HTTP extension would probably work but if possible I'd like to avoid using any kind of extensions...

Comment: No, php must preform a http request, but you could mayby use some shell script and execute that from php if you what to avoid http

Answer (score 1):

fopen() wouldn't support http requests so you can use `file_get_content()` in your scanario. For more detail please read [fopen()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fopen.php) and [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) from php.net.